# Symfony 3.2 Doctrine2 ORM хранение сложных запросов в виде классов

Tags: symfony, doctrine2, dql

Доброго времени суток, знатоки Symfony
Уже третий день изучаю Symfony 3.2
Научился обращаться к нескольким базам данных и немного попробовал Doctrine 2

Все получилось. Подскажите пожалуйста где мне хранить библиотеку запросов к базе данных, чтобы мне не приходилось использовать повторные запросы в различных контроллерах.

Если не понятно поясню

есть контроллер к примеру этот
src/ParserBundle/EmployeesController.php

в нем естьобращзение

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ParserBundle:Provider');
$providers = $repository ->findAll();
```

есть класс по запросам к базе данных к примеру этот src/ParserBundle/Entity/Provider.php

то как делать сложные запросы я могу почитать из документации Doctrine 2, а вот где мне их хранить что бы не дублировать? И как к ним обращаться из основных контроллеров - есть документация об этом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Укажите в сущности класс репозиторий. 
   к примеру:

   ```
   namespace App\AcmeBundle\Entity;    
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
   use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

   /**
    * Country
    *
    * @ORM\Table()
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\AcmeBundle\Repository\CountryRepository")
    */
   class Country extends BaseEntity {
       // ....
   }
   ```
2. Cоздайте класс репозиторий.

   ```
   namespace App\AcmeCDBBundle\Repository;
   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

   /**
    * CountryRepository
    */

   class CountryRepository extends EntityRepository
   {

       public function findAll()
       {
           return $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
                           ->innerJoin('q.translations', 't')
                           ->where("t.locale = :locale")
                           ->setParameter('locale', 'ru')
                           ->orderBy('t.name', 'ASC')
                           ->getQuery()
                           ->getResult();
       }

   }
   ```

После можно обращится к запросу из репозитория.

```
$country = $this->em->getRepository('AppAcmeBundle:Country')->findAll();
```

P.S не могу красиво код выделить.